# MySQL datetime format to dd/mm/yy 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, datetime, alter-table

How can I alter a Mysql table time stamp to such as the following:

```
dd/mm/yy 00:00:00
```

I tried:

> ALTER TABLE `TbMessage` MODIFY startdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;

But is not the formate as i thought:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

can some one help me? Because the date which i am receiving for the table is in the format DD/MM/YYYY from a SQL Database. I cant chnage the formate in the database of SQL.

Comment: How you represent the datetime that is stored in the DB is another matter. You can convert the timestamp in your selects.

Comment: Are sure about it? Why not handle the datetime with your programming language, much better.

Comment: how can i do it.. i am not sure about it. but i also want the date format in such a way as like the above.

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: If i want to do it in programming.. it is difficult because it is a bigchange throught out the application i feel its better to change in DB.

Comment: if you had applyed good pratics programming i belive that is easy to create just one function that you can call everywhere to handle just this...

Comment: I did that... i know the good programming.. but the system which given data is now in that format.. i am not that good as you suggested... to suggest the persons who developed SQL DB. sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `timestamp`/`datetime` is always stored the same way in the database. It is the representation in your selects that you can influence.

For that you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). Example:

```
select date_format(datetime_column, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s') 
from your_table
```

And if you want to store `date` and `time` you should rather use the `datetime` data type. So I recommend to use

```
ALTER TABLE TbMessage 
MODIFY `startdate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''startdate' datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL' at line 2

Comment: ALTER TABLE TbMessage MODIFY  'startdate'DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

Comment: Don't use quotes around the column name. Leave them or use backticks